# Не проходит миграция в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Создал миграцию, но кроме встроенных миграций (migration,user), другие не проходят. Удаляю, таблицы, провожу миграцию заново - та же ошибка. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После некоторых манипуляций (удаления таблиц и ввода `migrate:install`) появилась ошибка

```html
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long;
   max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_uniq
  ue`(`email`))



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long;
   max key length is 767 bytes.
```

Comment: ошибка говорит о том, что у вас таблица `users` уже существует, если таблицы нету, но ошибка осталась, попробуйте очистить таблицу `migrations`

Comment: В таблицу миграции ничего не пишется.

Comment: попробуйте выполнить эту команду `php artisan migrate:reset`, а затем снова сделать миграцию

Comment: иногда на хостингах ограничаивают длину текстового поля и текстовых индексов не 255 символами, а короче. Наприрме, email  у вас по-умолчанию 255. Сократите, скажем, до 100.

Answer (score 1):

В Laravel c версии 5.4 изменены характеристики баз данных по умолчанию и в ранних варсиях mysql может появляться ошибка `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long`

Чтобы исправить необходимо поправить файл `AppServiceProvider.php`

```html
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```